# How get an prop of Object key in a Dictionary C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have this homework, I have only 1 problem, and I don't know the solution. We have this class, and we musn't create another variables or methods...

I have a **beers** *dictionary* with **< Beer object, int income >**. But the method has got only the Beer object's name (prop), not the object.

And I don't have another idea, how can I get the Beer object's name from a Dictionary

I have only 2 idea, but these don't work.

The first is I tried use a ContainsKey() method. The second is an foreach iteration

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PubBeer
{
    public class Beer
    {
        string name;
        int price; 
        double alcohol;


        public string Name{ get { return name; } }

        public int Price{ get; set; }

        public double Alcohol{ get { return alcohol;} }

        public Sör(string name, int price, double alcohol)
        {
            this.name= name;
            this.price= price;
            this.alcohol= alcohol;
        }


        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is Beer)
            {
                Beer other = (Beer)obj;
                return this.name== other.name;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class Pub
    {

        int income;

        IDictionary<Beer, int> beers= new Dictionary<Beer, int>();


        public int Income{ get; set; }


        public int Sold(string beerName, int mug)
        {
           // Here the problem

            beers; // Here I want to like this: beers.Contains(beerName)
                  //  beers.ContainsKey(Object.Name==beerName) or someone like this 

           // foreach (var item in beers)
           // {
           //     item.Key.Name== beerName;
           //  }


        }
...
```

Comment: May I suggest changing your key. Searching through (possibly) every key in a dictionary ruins how efficient a dictionary is.

Comment: @m-y you are indeed right but if this is his homework probably his teacher wants him to learn something (linq querying maybe?)

Comment: I dont think linq... cause he isn't speak about the linq-s only interfaces at the last lessons... but this is the homework

Comment: @m-y and we musn't changing the key, The prof give an basic code, and I have to make up. If I can use LINQ-s it will be much better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LINQ to query over the collection of Keys.

```
//Throws an error if none or more than one object has the same name.
var beer = beers.Keys.Single(b => b.Name == beerName);

beers[beer] = ...;

// -or -

//Selects the first of many objects that have the same name.
//Exception if there aren't any matches.
var beer = beers.Keys.First(b => b.Name == beerName);

beers[beer] = ...;

// -or -

//Selects the first or default of many objects.
var beer = beers.Keys.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == beerName);

//You'll need to null check
if (beer != null)
{
    beers[beer] = ...;
}

// etc...
```

---

Update: NON-LINQ Alternative

```
Beer myBeer;

foreach (var beer in beers.Keys)
{
    if (beer.Name == beerName)
    {
        myBeer = beer;
        break;
    }
}

if (myBeer != null)
{
    beers[myBeer] = ...;
}
```

Comment: It's not bad, but I must use this two imports: `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Any()` on the Keys collection:

```
if (beers.Keys.Any(x => x.Name == beerName))
{
}
```

In the worst case this would have to look through all beers though - if you usually look up beers by name you should consider making the beer name the key and the beer object itself the value in the dictionary.

Once you have identified that such a beer exists you can use `First()` to select it:

```
 Beer myBeer = beers.First(x => x.Key.Name == beerName).Key;
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` would be more efficient than an `Any` + `First`. You can null check after you get back the `myBeer` value.

Comment: true - I wasn't sure whether OP just wants to do a check whether the item exists, or actually get the item

Comment: It's not bad, but I must use this two imports: `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;` so I can't call the Any and First methods :(

Comment: you cannot use `using System.Linq;` ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use Keys property

```
beers.Keys.Where(p => p.name == beername )
```

or

```
beers.Keys.FirstOrDefault(p => p.name == beername)
```